# How do I add a tooltip to a specific jsTree node

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have nodes that seem to overlay another area and I can't seem to contain it properly. If you have an idea of how to do that then I would accept that solution as well. Seeing that many of the node strings could be potentially very long it may be a good idea to add a tooltip to the node...

```
my script...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#jstree').jstree({

    plugins: ["themes","html_data", "state"],
    'core' : {
         'themes' : {
        'theme' : "apple",
        'dots' : true,
        'icons' : false
    },
        'data' : jsonTreeData
    }
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
     var href = data.node.a_attr.href;
     var parentId = data.node.a_attr.parent_id;
     if(href == '#')
     return '';

     window.open(href);

});
$('#jstree').slimScroll({
    height: '400px'
});
```

```
<div class="col-xl-3" style="background-color:#eeeeee; 
border-right:thin solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">


<div class="row" 
style="width: auto;margin: 0px;padding-left:5px;
padding-right: 5px;padding-top: 10px;">

<div id="jstree" class="treeview"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your html code too?

Comment: @Murali -- I used ellipses so I'm not too concerned about the width or the over text right now...plus I'm using a scrollbar so its best to just use the tooltip. The HTML is pretty messy because it does have all of the inline elements... but I will  post it

Answer (score 2):

For adding tooltip to a node, you can use a_attr attribute while preparing the data by adding `title`. You can use hyperlink as well in the same attributes.

You can use the json data as below:

```
var jsondata = [
    { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node", "a_attr": {href:'http://example1.com', title:'Simple root node tooltips'} },
    { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2", "a_attr": {href:'http://example2.com', title:'Root node 2 tooltips'} },
    { "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1",  "a_attr": {href:'http://example3.com', title:'Child 1 tooltips'} },
    { "id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2",  "a_attr": {href:'http://example4.com', title:'Child 2 tooltips'} }
];
```

It will do the rest. You can have a look at the simple and complete working example below in [jsTree-tooltips-example-with-linked-node](https://everyething.com/jsTree-tooltips-example-with-linked-node).